# Windows.Web.Http in Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Quick question: is it possible to use Windows.Web.Http in a Windows Forms application? I can't find anything related to it. Used it in a Windows Phone project before and really love it's behaviour. Also it's recommended by Microsoft, because it uses the RFC-standard.

But I can't use it in my Windows Forms application right now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

It has a very similar HttpClient class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I know System.Net.Http - but I really want to use Windows.Web.Http. It's more intuitive for me.